# MySQL check for duplicate entries in one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, duplicates, one-to-many

I have two tables in one-to-many relationship. I want to check if there is any duplicate entry in the mapping table.

customers:

```
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid                        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment |
| active                     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     |         |                |
| locked                     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     |         |                |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

items_mapping:

```
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment |
| customer_uid | int(11)       | NO   |     |         |                |
| device_uid   | int(11)       | NO   |     |         |                |
| offered      | float(11,2)   | NO   |     |         |                |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

How do I check if there is any customer, in the table table items_mapping, who has duplicate device_uid?

In short, this will work:

```
+-------+--------------+------------+---------+
| uid   | customer_uid | device_uid | offered |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------+
|  1132 |   53442      |      24    |  2.00   |
|  8242 |   53442      |      45    |  4.00   |
| 15122 |   53442      |      12    |  5.00   |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------+
```

But it shouldn't be:

```
+-------+--------------+------------+---------+
| uid   | customer_uid | device_uid | offered |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------+
|  1132 |   53442      |      24    |  2.00   |
|  8242 |   53442      |      45    |  4.00   |
| 15122 |   53442      |      24    |  2.00   |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: is it possible two different customers (customer_uid) to have one and the same device (device_uid)?

Comment: Yes, many customers can have the same offer from the same device, but they can not have same offer in one customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by `customer_uid` and `device_uid` together with `having` clause:

```
SELECT
    customer_uid,
    device_uid,
    COUNT(device_uid) count_device_uid
FROM
    items_mapping
GROUP BY
    customer_uid,
    device_uid
HAVING
    COUNT(device_uid) > 1
```

This will give you all customers with duplicated `device_uid`

Comment: omg, really? **facepalm myself. I can't accept the answer too quick, man. You gotta wait.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it runs but this should give your result:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*),
    customer_id,
    device_uid,
FROM 
    items_mapping
GROUP BY
    device_uid, customer_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: You have a correct answer as of mitkosoft, but I like it when he puts customer_uid first in the GROUP BY statement.